# A sort of modified geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I was wondering if there are any hints on how to manage this series
$$
\sum_{i=2}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (1-cj^{\beta-1})=(1-c)+(1-c)(1-c2^{\beta-1})+(1-c)(1-c2^{\beta-1})(1-c3^{\beta-1})...
$$
with $0<c<1$ and $0\leq \beta\leq 1$, which for $\beta=1$ reduces to the geometric series.

Comment: Please read tag summaries before using tags. This is not what the [tag:geometric-probability] tag is for.

Comment: Sorry; so there is a problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475450/geometric-series-equivalency), too

Comment: There is, thanks; I removed the tag there, too.