# Geometric Series Equivalency

Tags: summation, geometric-series

This is supposed to be easy, but somehow I am kinda stuck on this.

We can write

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}kp^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}$$

But one little trick to prove that the mean of a geometric random variable equals $\frac{1}{p}$ is to claim

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)p^k$$

However, I think **the second equation** is not true since it implies that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)p^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}$$
which is apparently false.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Write out the first few terms of each series.

Comment: I know the terms are identical. But how would you explain the third equation because if the first and the second equations are true, the third equation should also be true, which is not the case.

Comment: Why do you think it is false?

Comment: When $k=0$, $kp^{k-1}=0$. So the equation is valid.

Comment: I just edited the question. I'm just saying that if the first equation is true, the second equation is true, this should imply that the third equation is true. But it is obvious that the third equation is false.

Comment: Your "apparently false" third equation is true.

Comment: Explain "obvious".

Comment: If you write out the first few terms of the third equations, they are not the same?

Comment: @Chappers Not only the OP but lots of other mathematicians use words like "obvious" or "clear" or "trivial" when they're about to say something that's wrong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Exactly. See also [the phrasebook](http://www.maia.ub.es/~ruben/common.html).

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)p^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}$$
can be proved by rewriting
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}$$
as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp^{k-1},$$
since the first term (for $k = 0$) is just
$$0\cdot{p^{0-1}} = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To examine the equivalency of two series, I thought we should compare corresponding terms, i.e, when k=0, the corresponding two terms in the series need to be equal, etc ?

Comment: @JackShi, $k$ is just an index of summation for both series.  Perhaps, to rectify your confusion, you can rewrite the series as
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)p^j = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1},$$
where I've changed the index of summation in the LHS to $j$.

So if you write out the actual terms of each series, you go:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{(j+1)p^j} = 1 + 2p + 3p^2 + 4p^3 + \ldots$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1} = 0 + 1 + 2p + 3p^2 + 4p^3 + \ldots.$$

QED.